# Image picker scanned to null flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

File _image;
final picker = ImagePicker();

```
Future getImage() async {
  final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

  setState(() {
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    } else {
      print('No image selected.');
    }
  });
}
```

output:

> D/MediaScannerConnection(16161): Scanned /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxx.xxxx/files/Pictures/9d9ed6a1-292c-428a-bf24-38ea1a58742c6940060118053310767.jpg to null

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error show up because you need to clean your build folder. Try to do `flutter clean` and rebuild again.

Comment: hi, i tried this and it didn't work. please, could you help with other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

if (pickedFile == null) {
  return null;
}

Directory appDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
File newImage = File(appDirectory.path + 'fileName');
newImage.writeAsBytes(File(pickedFile.path).readAsBytesSync());

setState(() {
  _image = newImage;
  print(newImage.path + ' test');
});
```

Comment: hi, i tried this. it still scans the image to null. please. any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() where can you get this method ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      // Hide the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Kindacode.com',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  File? _image;

  final _picker = ImagePicker();
  // Implementing the image picker
  Future<void> _openImagePicker() async {
    final XFile? pickedImage =
    await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedImage.path);
      });
      print(pickedImage);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Kindacode.com'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(35),
            child: Column(children: [
              Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Select An Image'),
                  onPressed: _openImagePicker,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 35),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                child: _image != null
                    ? Image.file(_image!, fit: BoxFit.cover)
                    : const Text('Please select an image'),
              )
            ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

i share my code here just follow my code . i think you will get where the mistake is .

Comment: i am also facing this problem . now i getride of this problem . it works fine .